# Freemarker reference theme.properties in template

Tags: properties, struts2, themes, freemarker

I am very new to this and have to migrate an existing web app (that I do not know much about) to Weblogic (12.2.1.4). I had to upgrade the version of struts (2.0.11.2 --> 2.3.1) which also came with a newer version of Freemarker (2.3.8 --> 2.3.18).

The *template* directory has subdirectories for the different themes.
Under *ajax* for example I have a file theme.properties containing this line:

```
parent=xhtml
```

A *head.ftl* then contains this include:

```
<#include "/${parameters.templateDir}/${themeProperties.parent}/head.ftl" />
```

However this throws the following error in the browser:

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> themeProperties.parent  [in template "template/ajax/head.ftl" at line 2, column 41]
```

I believe this was working on the old server.

**Is there some new way or syntax to reference the content of that properties file?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like replacing

```
${themeProperties.parent}
```

with

```
${parameters.expandTheme}
```

seems to work